# import statement causing issue in dist packages

Tags: python

I installed vnfmanager from this git repository . Installation went fine

```
https://github.com/TCS-TelcoCloud/vnfmanager.git
```

The package got installed under the directory

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/

vnfmanager-2015.1.0-py2.7.egg
          |
          |---- vnfmanager (Folder)
                 |
                 |---- vnf_manager.py
```

The main function resides in vnf_manager.py.

After the installation, when i start the service, am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/vnf-manager", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('vnfmanager==2015.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'vnf-manager')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 357, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2478, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2192, in load
    ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named vnf_manager
```

Hence, i used PDB to find the place where the exception occurs. That took me till

```
pdb /usr/local/bin/vnf-manager --config-file /etc/vnfsvc/vnfsvc.conf --vnfm-conf-dir /var/lib/vnfsvc/78c1f834-fd4f-4fba-b15e-42707a501fcd/ --log-file /var/lib/vnfsvc/78c1f834-fd4f-4fba-b15e-42707a501fcd/vnfm.log --uuid 78c1f834-fd4f-4fba-b15e-42707a501fcd
> /usr/local/bin/vnf-manager(3)<module>()
-> __requires__ = 'vnfmanager==2015.1.0'
(Pdb) b /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py:2190
Breakpoint 1 at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py:2190
(Pdb) c
vnfmanager 2015.1.0 ------------DIST-------
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py(2190)load()
-> print self.module_name, "-------------self.module_name---------------"
(Pdb) print self.module_name
vnfmanager.vnf_manager
(Pdb) c
vnfmanager.vnf_manager -------------self.module_name---------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 1314, in main
    pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 1233, in _runscript
    self.run(statement)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 400, in run
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/bin/vnf-manager", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('vnfmanager==2015.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'vnf-manager')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 357, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2480, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.
```

The file that is causing error is /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py. and the line where the exception occurs is

```
 print self.module_name, "-------------self.module_name---------------"
        entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(), globals(),
            ['__name__'])

 print entry, "-----------------------ENTRY--------------------------"


self.module_name contains - vnfmanager.vnf_manager
__name__ contains - pkg_resources
```

Am not really sure , why the module is not getting imported even though it exists in the path.

The same code is running fine for me in the another server. Please help

EDIT:

Tried installing using virtualenv. Still getting the same error.

```
(test3)nfv@nfv-controller-2:~/nfvorch/test/vnfmanager$ /usr/local/bin/vnf-manager --config-file /etc/vnfsvc/vnfsvc.conf --vnfm-conf-dir /var/lib/vnfsvc/78c1f834-fd4f-4fba-b15e-42707a501fcd/ --log-file /var/lib/vnfsvc/78c1f834-fd4f-4fba-b15e-42707a501fcd/vnfm.log --uuid 78c1f834-fd4f-4fba-b15e-42707a501fcd
vnfmanager 2015.1.0 ------------DIST-------
vnfmanager.vnf_manager -------------self.module_name---------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/vnf-manager", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('vnfmanager==2015.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'vnf-manager')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 357, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2480, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2192, in load
    ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named vnf_manager
```

Comment: Any reason why you are not using a virtualenv?

Comment: In the previous server, i installed with the same commands and everything went fine. In this server, i tried using virtualenv too. But , there are lot of dependency libraries needed for this package. Even though everything exists in the server, when i create virutal environment and install vnfmanager, it is asking me to install dependent libraries. Ex: Yaml .

Comment: Well that is what a virtualenv is for. It provides an isolated environment. If you need to use installed system packages, you should use : virtualenv --system-site-packages ENV

Comment: but the error that am getting looks very simple python error. There should be something to reference the package . even though the package exists ,  its not getting referenced properly .

Comment: @TheGeorgeous , i installed it again using virtual environment . Am getting the same issue.